# How can I get facebook window height from iframe?

Tags: javascript

I want to get facebook window height using javascript from my iframe. However window.innerHeight gives me the height of the iframe. How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Not sure but i think it's impossible, you will get access denied trying to access iframe content. But why do you need it? requesting facebook social plugins you can set width and height u need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your're using the Facebook JavaScript SDK, you could use `FB.Canvas.getPageInfo()`

```
FB.Canvas.getPageInfo(
    function(info) {
        console.log('Height: ' + info.clientHeight);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the iframe's parent window, and get its height instead.
You could try `parent.window.innerHeight` instead, and that should fetch the right answer.

The following works if the document it's in is included in another document through an iframe:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert(parent.window.innerHeight);
</script>
```

**Note that this might not work for cross-domain requests, i.e. if you're embedding something not hosted on the same domain as the main site, which might be the case for facebook apps**